# Segmentation fault, cannot increment

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, segmentation-fault, structure

There is a function that asks the user which text file to open, opens it and then passes the array of structures that was passed into the function along with the file pointer to another function that reads in data from file into the structure. The array structure for testing purposes only has the value `char name[25];`. I can assign one line at a time from the file to the same structure index all I want but when I try an increment it I get a segmentation fault no matter what approach I've taken.
The structure has been type defined as well.

The code is:

```
void oSesame(char usrTxt[], int len, FILE * pFile, Country * p)
{
    pFile = fopen(usrTxt, "rw");

    if(pFile != NULL)
    {
        readIn(pFile, &p);  
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error opening %s , check your spelling and try again.\n", usrTxt);
    }

}

void readIn(FILE * pfile, Country ** p)
{   
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        fgets((*p[i]).cntName, MAX_COUNTRY_LENGTH, pfile);      
    }
    fclose(pfile);
}
```

The header file:

```
//Header.h
#define COUNTRY_MAX 10
#define MAX_COUNTRY_LENGTH 25
#define MAX_CAPITAL_LENGTH 25

typedef struct country
{
    char cntName[MAX_COUNTRY_LENGTH];
    char capName[MAX_CAPITAL_LENGTH];
    double population;
}Country;

int ask(char * usrTxt);
void oSesame(char usrTxt[], int len, FILE * pFile, Country * p);
void readIn(FILE * pFile, Country ** p);
```

The main code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    //for testing within main
#include <string.h>   //for testing within main
#include "headers.h"

int main()
{
    int len;
    FILE * fileP;
    char UI[25];

    Country c[10];
    Country * ptr;
    ptr = c;

    len = ask(UI);

    oSesame(UI, len, fileP, ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: did you actually allocate *any* memory for `p[i]->cntName`?

Comment: I updated the question sorry for the inconvenience and i did allocate, not dynamically but I'm hoping that wont be necessary.

Comment: 0) `rw` --> `r+`,  1) `(*p[i]).cntName` --> `((*p)[i]).cntName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `Country**` for some reason and then handling it as `*p[index]`. This is wrong. You could use `(*p)[index]` but the correct way is not to take a reference to the `Country*` in the first place.

The way you're doing it means you have a pointer to pointer to `Country`. When you index that you are moving to next pointer to pointer, which is not the same as moving to the next pointer. Undefined behaviour happens.

Comment: This did the trick. Any suggestions for removing the complication from the process?